# Creating an Eclipse RCP application installer using InstallShield

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, installshield

I want to create a 64-Bit installer from an Eclipse RCP 3.x and 4.x hybrid application, please find below points for the same

1. JDK 1.8 64-Bit - to compile/build our source code with JDK 1.8 64-Bit
2. Eclipse RCP application contains few 3.x and 4.x (4.5 to be specific) components
3. We don't want to ship JRE with Installer
4. InstallShield options I can see,
   1. InstallShield,
   2. InstallShield Premier (could be version 2023 R1) and
   3. InstallShield Professional (could be version 2021)

my questions,

1. Assuming above points which InstallShield product I should choose??
2. JDK will be required for installing the selected InstallShield product or not?? if yes, which JDK will be required??
3. Can we get a trail version of selected InstallShield product to confirm that we need the same product based on our requirement before actually purchasing it??
4. Please suggest better alternative if any.

Thank you in advance. Looking forward for your help.

Comment: This question is too broad. Nowadays RCP applications are build with [Tycho](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseTycho/article.html) and this will compile the sources with the Eclipse compiler, not with `javac` of a JDK. Recent versions of the Java platform require Java 17 or higher. A JRE can be easily included via [Eclipse JustJ](https://eclipse.dev/justj/) as an update-able feature. I'm using [NSIS](https://nsis.sourceforge.io/Download) to create an installer for Windows: https://github.com/howlger/IDEalized/blob/a2937a42fc74e3757d269b011e01d4702cb324cf/product/pom.xml#L155-L238

Comment: With the [WiX Toolset](https://wixtoolset.org/) you can create state of the art .msi installer for Windows. And since the WiX Toolset is open source, you do not have the limitations you mentioned.

Comment: @howlger actually product is already built with Tycho but moving forward I want to create an installer/single .exe file out of that built product using InstallShield. Any thoughts on InstallShield questions as I have mentioned above?? Meanwhile I will also check if NSIS and WiX Toolset can help me out as you mentioned. Thank you!

Comment: Nowadays I would prefer .msi (e.g. via the WiX Toolset) than .exe installers (via NSIS, InstallShield, etc.) because .msi files are smaller and what is recommended by Microsoft. I only referred to NSIS as an example of how to build an installer within the Tycho build.

Comment: Its more clear to me now. Let me see about compatibility of all the applications I need based on my requirements. Thank you again!

Answer (score -1):

You need to first make a drawup chart of that and then make it a ui and then have it connected to a memory server in your computer in order to make changes of new installments that it just adds and then yes installer fast but since

Comment: Thanks for your response. I did not get it much what you explained but let me check.